# Ordering a list of knockout components

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

I have a list of knockout components

```
  <!-- ko foreach: myComponents -->
  <div data-bind="component: $data"></div>
  <!-- /ko-->
```

Here's how I create my observable array of component definitions and this renders as expected.

```
createComponents = function(jsonData) {
    var components;
    components = _.map(jsonData, function( jsonItem ) {
       switch (jsonItem.type) {
         case 0:
           return {
             name: "component-type-0",
             params: jsonItem
           }; 
         case 1:
           return {
             name: "component-type-1",
             params: jsonItem
           };
         default:
           throw new Error("No case for type " + jsonItem.type);
    });

    this.myComponents( components );
  };
```

However I'm not sure how to sort them.  My array only has the `name` and the `jsonData` but not the viewModel that's created when the component is created.

I'd like the items in the array to remain as components so to keep them easily reusable.

Is there a way to access the viewModel that is created so I can sort based on a property of that?

Comment: I suppose you could manually fetch the viewmodels using requireJS (or whatever module loader you use) and check the property. But imo this smells like bad design. The sort order should depend on the data, not on some hardcoded property in the viewmodel. If the viewmodel property isn't hardcoded, but depends on the data you pass, then it should be possible to apply the same logic in your sort function, using the data directly. (By data I mean your `jsonItem`.) TL;DR: You shouldn't need the viewmodels to be able to sort your array. Use the raw data instead.

Comment: True, this is the way that I'm getting around it just now but it's quite smelly in itself.  The logic for providing a ordering/sort integer should be encapsulated inside the viewmodel of the component as it's logic related to that.  Say I had 10 different components all which calculate their sort index slightly differently I'd have to have some kind of separate sort provider when base it on the type.  It would just be nicer for each viewmodel to have a function encapsulated I think.

Comment: I don't agree that this logic should be inside the viewmodel itself. Sorting will be relative to other items (components), and thus belongs in a separate module that 'knows' all the components. But this is all conceptually speaking and it's a thin line that depends a bit on your semantics. Can you elaborate a bit more on how you determine the 'sort integer' for a component? And what are your final results supposed to be? Simply ordering by component type, or is it based on the data, or a combination of both? It's still hard to see what value the method on the viewmodel adds.

Comment: It's actually a timeline of historical events.  For most items it'll be something like a date however we have multiple `call to action` items which aren't timeline events but we want them in specific places.  Perhaps you're right in that there should be a separate sorting module.  It might make it more testable.

Answer (score 2):

By the next version of Knockout, there might be a way to access to the component view model from the parent, but it's not part of Knockout at present. (See https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1475 and  https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1533)

I've come up with a way to include a callback for component bindings that's called with the component view model.

Here is an example of it working to sort a set of components: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/a6f3fmzt/

The first part is a custom binding that takes a `callback` parameter and injects it into the `params` value for the `component` binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.componentWithCallback = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, ignored1, ignored2, bindingContext) {
        function newValueAccessor() {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if (value.callback) {
                value.params = ko.utils.extend(
                    { callback: value.callback },
                    value.params);
            }
            return value;
        }
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(
            element, { component: newValueAccessor }, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

The second part is to wrap the component loader to call the callback function once the view model instance is created.

```
ko.components.defaultLoader.loadViewModel = (function (original) {
    return function (errorCallback, viewModelConfig, callback) {
        function newCallback(createViewModel) {
            return callback(function (params, componentInfo) {
                var componentVM = createViewModel.call(this, params, componentInfo);
                if (params.callback) {
                    params.callback.call(null, componentVM);
                }
                return componentVM;
            });
        }
        return original.call(this, errorCallback, viewModelConfig, newCallback);
    }
}(ko.components.defaultLoader.loadViewModel));
```